# Choose Highest Value Column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need your help. A dataframe stores the probabilities of three categories, as follows:

```
dict_test = {'series': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
              'cat_1': [.02, .02, .81, .72, .01, .3, .45],
              'cat_2': [.02, .02, .14, .2, .99, .45, .4],
              'cat_3': [.96, .96, .05, .08, .00, .25, .15]}

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_test)
```

I need to create a new column to store which category has the highest probability. What I've been able to do so far is select the highest probability using the agg function:

```
df['choice'] = df.drop('series', axis = 1).agg(max, axis = 1)
```

The result I need is exemplified with this dataframe:

```
dict_test = {'series': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
              'cat_1': [.02, .02, .81, .72, .01, .3, .45],
              'cat_2': [.02, .02, .14, .2, .99, .45, .4],
              'cat_3': [.96, .96, .05, .08, .00, .25, .15],
             'result': ['cat_3', 'cat_3', 'cat_1', 'cat_1', 'cat_2', 'cat_2', 'cat_1']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_test)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)

```py
df['result'] = df.filter(regex='^cat').idxmax(axis=1)
```

Comment: Why use a filter? I didn't understand.

Comment: `agg` needs to be applied on the 3 `cat_*` columns only.   
In your example you used `drop` which is equivalent, but it seems to me that `filter` is more practical if other columns are present in real data.

Comment: No need for `agg`, just use `.idxmax(axis=1)`

Comment: good point, thanks